# How to pass array of string into a FastReport variable?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

My plan is to pass an array of string into a FastReport

Here's my code (stripped from all irrelevant parts and error handling):

```
var
  elements: TStringArray; // TStringArray = array of string;
begin
  FR := TfrxReport.Create(Self);
  FR.LoadFromFile(...);
  FR.Variables['dataArray'] := elements; // <-- Error here
  FR.ShowReport;
  FR.Free;
end;
```

But I get the error, indicating that I can not assign an array to a string that way:

> Could not convert variant of type (array OleStr) into type String

However if I assign `'['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']'` to a `dataArray` variable *within* FastReport editor it works just fine - I can access `dataArray[1]` and etc.

So my question is - How to properly assign a variable of type `array of string` to FastReport variable?

Comment: I don't have a copy of `FastReport` to hand, but I know it uses an internal copy of `FastScript`. If you can gain access to this you should be able to make the Delphi variable available to the script using the script's `AddVariable` method. e.g. `FR.Script.AddVariable('elements', 'Array', elements);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a copy of `FastReport` to hand, but I know it uses an internal copy of `FastScript`. If you can gain access to this you should be able to make the Delphi variable available to the script using the script's `AddVariable` method. e.g.

`FR.Script.AddVariable('elements', 'Array', elements);`